# what is a pure periodic function?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions, time-series

I'm not exactly sure what is meant by a "pure-periodic" function. 
I've read several places that it just means that each period has an identical duration... is it really that simple?

How do I tell if a function is "pure-periodic" using frequency and the period?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual term in mathematics is "periodic"; "pure" is just there for emphasis, I suspect.  A function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ is periodic with period $p$ if $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just to distinguish between functions like $\sin(t)$ and functions like [$e^{-t}\sin(t)$](http://math.mercyhurst.edu/~griff/courses/m240/ODE_gifs/expTrig.gif). The latter is not periodic (in the "pure" sense), since there is no $\ T\ |\ f(t+T) = f(t)\ \forall\ t$, but it does a kind of oscillation-like thing that some might call "pseudo-periodicity". Like the other answer here says, "pure" is probably just for emphasis that the function satisfies the condition we have mentioned and is definitely not just pseudo-periodic, etc.